# Moving files into a file structure on a monthly basis

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to move files every month into a file structure, the structure is like so:

```
Year >> Quarter >> Month >> FileType
```

The log files are automatically placed into a log folder - I want to m,ove any of these files into this structure above.

I tried the following:

```
function moveFiles{
# The three parameters. 
param([string]$sourceDir, [string]$type, [string]$destinationDir) 
# Move the files
Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Include $type | Move-Item -Destination $destinationDir -  Force
}
```

However each month it is moving every file into the new month, I know this is to do with the recurse but I removed it and no files were moved.

Any help would be appreciated.

How I am calling the function:

```
$sourceDir = "C:\Logs"
$destinationExcelDir = ($monthFolder + "\Excel Files");
#Moving all Excel files from logs folder to Archive
moveFiles $sourceDir "*.xls" $destinationExcelDir
```

Using `write-host` I can confirm both paths are correct and also different however I am trying to copy the files into subfolders in the same main directory.

E.g. `$destinationExcelDir` is "C:\Logs\2014\quarter 4\November\Excel"

Comment: the problem is related to how you call the function so please include the code that does it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort the files in C:\logs by their last write time, the following function revision should help.  You would only have to supply the path with a wild card containing the extension and the last folder name in the path name as arguments to the function.

Example Usage: moveFiles C:\Logs*.xls "Excel Files"

```
function moveFiles {
    param(
    [string]$source,
    [string]$destinationDir
    )

Get-ChildItem $source -file | foreach {
    $year = $_.LastWriteTime.Year

    # Switch statement to get the quarter name
    switch -regex ($_.LastWriteTime.Month) {
        "[1-3]" {$quarter = 'Quarter 1'}
        "[4-6]" {$quarter = 'Quarter 2'}
        "[7-9]" {$quarter = 'Quarter 3'}
        "[10-12]" {$quarter = 'Quarter 4'}

    }
    # Switch statement to get the month name
    switch ($_.LastWriteTime.Month) {
        '1' {$month = 'January'}
        '2' {$month = 'Feburary'}
        '3' {$month = 'March'}
        '4' {$month = 'April'}
        '5' {$month = 'May'}
        '6' {$month = 'June'}
        '7' {$month = 'July'}
        '8' {$month = 'August'}
        '9' {$month = 'September'}
        '10' {$month = 'October'}
        '11' {$month = 'November'}
        '12' {$month = 'December'}
    }

    # Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!(test-path "C:\Logs\$year\$quarter\$month\$destinationDir")) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "C:\Logs\$year\$quarter\$month\$destinationDir"
    }
    # Move the files into the correct folder
    move-item $_ "C:\Logs\$year\$quarter\$month\$destinationDir"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that has some parameters set to mandatory so it should prompt you for input if you don't provide it when you run it. Destination directory is set to pre-defined locations based on file type, but can be over-ridden if specified at run time. Month input is assumed to be a number. If this were to go into a production environment, I'd expect some input validations, confirmation prompts, and possibly result validations. Making this a wiki answer to see if anyone wants to add anything.

Usage:
Move-Files -sourceDir c:\temp -type xls -year 2014 -month 11

Over-ride:
Move-Files -sourceDir c:\temp -type xls -year 2014 -month 11 -destinationDir "Override Location"

```
Function Move-Files{
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$sourceDir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$type,
    [string]$destinationDir,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$year,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$month
)
# Add wildcard and period to search for all files of the given type by extension
[string]$searchtype = '*.' + $type
# Determine quarter of the year
if ($month -like "1" -or $month -like "2" -or $month -like "3"){[string]$quarter = "Quarter 1"}
elseif ($month -like "4" -or $month -like "5" -or $month -like "6"){[string]$quarter = "Quarter 2"}
elseif ($month -like "7" -or $month -like "8" -or $month -like "9"){[string]$quarter = "Quarter 3"}
elseif ($month -like "10" -or $month -like "11" -or $month -like "12"){[string]$quarter = "Quarter 4"}
# Read month number to pull month name
[string]$monthname = (get-date -Month $month).tostring("MMMM")
# Set destination based on file type.
if($type -like "xls" -and $destinationDir -like $null){[string]$destinationDir = "Excel Files"}
elseif($type -like "jpg" -and $destinationDir -like $null){[string]$destinationDir = "Image Files"}
elseif ($destinationDir -like $null){[string]$destinationDir = Read-Host 'Please enter destination directory.'}
# Build complete destination path
[string]$completeDir = $sourceDir + '\' + $year + '\' + $quarter + '\' + $monthname + '\' + $destinationDir
# Check for directory and create if not found
if (!(test-path $completeDir)) {[void](New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $completeDir)}
# Move the files
Get-ChildItem -Path $($sourceDir + "\" + $searchtype) | Move-Item -Destination $completeDir -Force
}
```